# Typescript - Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer

Tags: typescript

I have a function that is inferring the types however when i mock the response of this function it is complaining.

> 1. Argument of type '({ id: string; authentication_id: string; dtype: string; session: string; }[] | null)[]' is not assignable to parameter
>    of type 'readonly [null, any] | readonly [IFindUserWithAuthResponse[],
>    null] | Promise<readonly [null, any] | readonly
>    [IFindUserWithAuthResponse[], null]>'.
>    Type '({ id: string; authentication_id: string; dtype: string; session: string; }[] | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly
>    [IFindUserWithAuthResponse[], null]'.
>    Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.

```
   const mockFindUserWithAuthData = [
            [
                {
                    id: "123",
                    authentication_id: "123",
                    dtype: "checkpoint_login",
                    session: "123",
                },
            ],
            null,
        ];

onst mockFindUserWithAuth = jest.mocked(FindUserWithAuth);

mockFindUserWithAuth.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockFindUserWithAuthData); // ts error here
```

**function**

I use as const here so i dont have to manually write the return types.

```
const FindUserWithAuth: (auth_id: string) => Promise<readonly [IFindUserWithAuthResponse[], null] | readonly [null, any]>
```

```
interface IFindUserWithAuthResponse extends RowDataPacket {
    id: string;
    authentication_id: string;
    dtype: string;
    session: string;
}

export const FindUserWithAuth = async (auth_id: string) => {
    const query = `        
        SELECT u.*, a.id as authentication_id, a.dtype, a.session
        FROM user u
        JOIN authentication a on u.id = a.user_id
        WHERE a.id = ?
        AND a.deleted_at IS NULL
    `;

    const q = MySQLPreparedStatement(query, [auth_id]);
    try {
        const [rows, field] = await MySQLMaster.query<IFindUserWithAuthResponse[]>(q);
        return [rows, null] as const;
    } catch (err) {
        Logger.error({ method: "FindUserWithAuth", error: err, stack_trace: err.stack });
        return [null, err] as const;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This is untested, but if you add `as const` to your data, it should work:

```
   const mockFindUserWithAuthData = [
            [
                {
                    id: "123",
                    authentication_id: "123",
                    dtype: "checkpoint_login",
                    session: "123",
                },
            ],
            null,
        ] as const;
```

By default, something like this:

```
const a = [1, "4"];
```

will be typed as `(string | number)[]`, i.e. an array of arbitrary length whose items are strings or numbers.

On the other hand this:

```
const a = [1, "4"] as const;
```

tells the compiler that this is a 2-item tuple with a number as the first item and a string as the second (actually explicitly 1 as the first item and "4" as the second).

Comment: i tried this, it did not work